# CentOs eth2 wont start on reboot

Tags: networking, centos, reboot

I have Cent OS 6.4 inside my virtualbox with two ethernet devices. One is connected to the internet with NAT, the other is connected to the internal network.

here is my eth2 config file

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2 
DEVICE=eth2 
BOOTPROTO=none 
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes 
NAME='internal network'
NETWORK=10.0.1.0 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0 
IPADDR=10.0.1.27 
USERCTL=no
```

if I run

```
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

the interface gets set up and everything works, but I have to run that after each reboot.

How can I have that network configured after a reboot too. I thought **ONBOOT** was the only flag I needed.

Edit: I had run

```
# chkconfig network on
# chkconfig | grep network
  network           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Edit2:

The problem vas that NetworkManager was on and the settings got overriden. Solved it with:

```
chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

Comment: Maybe the network service itself isn't started in your default runlevel. Try `chkconfig --level $(who -r|awk '{print $2}') network on` as root.

Comment: I have also checked that and it's `network         0:off 1:off 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off`

Comment: @JosephR. It could be possible that something else is messing up my config files.

Comment: I wouldn't know. I haven't stuck with any RPM-based distro long enough to figure out how the network scripts worked. Maybe check the logs for errors/failures...

Comment: If your problem was solved, please consider answering your own question.

Answer (score -1):

```
chkconfig --level 3 5 network on
```

Comment: The OP edited the question to reflect that the network service is started in runlevels 3 and 5.